# How does a beta StackExchange site become non-beta?

Tags: discussion

What are the parameters which are taken into consideration when deciding that a certain site is needed?

Comment: Mostly you can find literature about that here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239949/287976

Comment: If by "non-beta" it means "graduated", SE stated that [when a site starts to consistently receive 10 questions/day, we’ll consider it for graduation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614). However, no new beta sites have graduated [since Oct 2017](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/290363)

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the proposals within the *Area 51* site for the site you want to know the answer to your question.

As a sample, go [check it out for DevOps.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97295?phase=beta). The beta-tab shows the current status (progress), indicating what is still needed for the site to become mature enough to "*graduate*" (= change from beta status to no-longer-beta).

Even though there appear to be exceptions, as soon as all 5 indicators have changed to **Excellent**, additional steps are taken to actually obsolete the beta status of the site, which may still take a few months or so.

PS: with the above in mind, if you want to help DevOps.SE to graduate, just try to post some more (good!) questions, and / or try to answer existing questions.

Comment: 3/5 are excellent at the moment. The daily amount of questions and number of answers per question is an issue currently.